# Can SQL Developer be used with the Athena JDBC Driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-athena

I'm trying to connect to Athena using the JDBC drivers provided by Amazon, and using SQL Developer as the client.  So far, I haven't had any luck with Java 1.8.181 and AthenaJDBC42-2.0.7.jar Has anyone had any luck on this front?  Before I try mixing up which versions of Java, JDBC driver, and/or SQL Developer, I thought I'd at least ask if anyone has been successful using SQL Developer with the Athena JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

SQL Developer doesn't allow for just any JDBC driver to be added...we restrict connectivity to the platforms we officially support for database migrations to the Oracle Database platform.

Athena doesn't have migration support, hence the lack of connectivity. If you need assistance with a migration, please send me a note.